# What's wrong with my sed replace?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to extract a users email from a perforce users command using regex. But for some reason I'm getting this problem. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
p4 user -o $user | grep 'Email:' | awk '/Email:/{i++}i==2' | sed -e 's/Email:  //g'
```

I'm getting this:
`Email:  perforce@master`

But the intent is to get just the stuff after `Email:`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need grep or sed when you're using awk. You didn't show the output of `p4 user -o $user` so it's a guess at what the input to awk would be but chances are this is what you need:

```
p4 user -o "$user" | awk '($1=="Email:") && c++{print $2; exit}'
```

but there may be an even simpler solution depending on what the output of `p4 ...` is.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match an exact number of spaces. That could be the problem. Your sed expression will also fail with a tab, for example. Try matching whitespace in general with something like:

```
sed -e 's/Email:[[:blank:]]*//g'
```